# Menu disappears when maximizing window from half screen

Tags: 11.10, unity

I often use the feature where I drag my window to the left or right side of the screen to make it fill half the screen.  Sometimes, when my window is like that, then I click to maximize it, it doesn't maximize, but the main menu(File/Edit/etc...) and the min/max/close buttons all disappear.  It doesn't happen every time, I don't know exactly what triggers it.  My browser is like that now as I type this.

What causes this, and how do I fix it(besides restarting the browser)?

[image]

Note the location of my cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Benjamin,

It's normal, as Ubuntu works with a global menu.
Try to move your cursor to the top area when your application is in fullscreen mode.

You'll see the menus and windows options, as expected.

*Edited*:

You're right. After try for a while, it happened to me too. You could try Ctrl+Alt+5 to quit this "problematic" mode.

This behavior is a bug, and a fix was commited, as [you can see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/861279).

Comment: You misunderstand.  The application will not go into fullscreen mode.  I know that you have to move your cursor to the top, that's the same even when it's not in fullscreen.  Either way, the menu does not show up.

Comment: I updated my post with a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. After try for a while, it happened to me too. It seems to be bug, You could try Ctrl+Alt+5 to quit this "problematic" mode.

Comment: Make that last comment your answer, and you've got it.